# How to recover files from deleted user partition (I have the password)

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs

I'm in deep, deep trouble. After a sad sequence of events (resized FAT32 via gparted, Windows wouldn't recognize it, used TestDisk and then a bug in the program removed all my partitions), I ended up with a DELETED user partition.

Fortunately, no data was actually damaged. TestDisk "just deleted" all my partitions and I have very poor hopes of ever getting my machine back in working order. So now I have to install fresh and use R-Studio to recover my files.

From what I can see from R-Studio analysis, I can recover pretty much all my files, no problem.

However, when I looked in my Linux user partition, it's all ecryptfs and I can't understand a single file name. It's all obfuscated. I don't remember ever setting a passphrase for my user partition so I assume I used the login password.

How can I recover my files after undeleting them with R-Studio? Keep in mind that I can't restore the partition, only get files from it back.

Comment: Can we back up a little here - how exactly did you recover files with R-Studio (which AFAIK is a data analysis / visualization tool)?

Comment: @steeldriver Hey! :). R-Studio can indeed fully recover files. I have to buy the full version ($80) for that. Until then, I can recover files up to 256 KB which I already did with good results (recovered the TestDisk log, it looks perfect). I'm quite confident by the looks of what I see in my other, unencrypted, partitions, that the data is in good integrity. Now the challenge is how to decrypt the files in the user partition using the password I have.

Comment: If you just damaged the partition table, you can rewrite it with a correct table and you are good to go.